# Buildfarm jobs can't access ros_buildfarm, ros_buildfarm_config repos

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

After setting deploying a buildfarm as outlined in the `buildfarm_deployment` and `ros_buildfarm` repository documentations, I noticed that most jobs fail with an error message similar to the following

```
python3 -u /home/jenkins-agent/workspace/Krel_arm_reconfigure-jobs/ros_buildfarm/scripts/release/run_release_reconfigure_job.py file:/tmp/deploy_ros_buildfarm/ros_buildfarm_config/index.yaml kinetic arm --distribution-repository-urls http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu --distribution-repository-key-files /home/jenkins-agent/workspace/Krel_arm_reconfigure-jobs/keys/0.key --groovy-script /tmp/reconfigure_jobs/reconfigure_jobs.groovy --dockerfile-dir /home/jenkins-agent/workspace/Krel_arm_reconfigure-jobs/docker_generate_release_jobs

python3: can't open file '/home/jenkins-agent/workspace/Krel_arm_reconfigure-jobs/ros_buildfarm/scripts/release/run_release_reconfigure_job.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It seems like the jobs require scripts from the `ros_buildfarm` repo but can't find it.

To test, I manually copied the repo into one of the job's workspace directories.

That overcame the previous error, but then the job fails with

```
docker run --rm --cidfile=/home/jenkins-agent/workspace/Krel_reconfigure-jobs/docker_generate_release_jobs/docker.cid -e=GIT_BRANCH= --net=host -v /home/jenkins-agent/workspace/Krel_reconfigure-jobs/ros_buildfarm:/tmp/ros_buildfarm:ro -v /home/jenkins-agent/.buildfarm:/home/buildfarm/.buildfarm:ro -v /home/jenkins-agent/workspace/Krel_reconfigure-jobs/reconfigure_jobs:/tmp/reconfigure_jobs release_reconfigure_jobs

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1410, in open_local_file
        stats = os.stat(localfile)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/deploy_ros_buildfarm/ros_buildfarm_config/index.yaml'
```

The file `/tmp/deploy_ros_buildfarm/ros_buildfarm_config/index.yaml` does exist (and contains the proper settings), but I assume it is not accessible from the docker container.

Can someone please explain to me how the jobs expect to access `ros_buildfarm` and `ros_buildfarm_config`?

Thanks in advance!

Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331213/buildfarm-jobs-can%27t-access-ros_buildfarm,-ros_buildfarm_config-repos/) by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-08-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-21**:
First thing to check: deployment was successful. Do this by checking the puppet log on all three hosts (master, repo and slave(s)). Any "error", "warning" or failure will lead to a partial deployment.

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2019-08-21**:
After following gvdhoorn's suggestion about checking the deployment success here's a next step:

Each job is configured to check out its own copy of the ros_buildfarm scripts. If you can share the full build log for one of the failures before you manually changed the workspace it might contain hints about why the checkout didn't occur.

**Comment by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) on 2019-08-21**:
@gvdhoorn
Thank you for your advice! I have checked the puppet log, and apart from some "deprecated" warnings at the beginning, there is one error message:

```
/Stage[main]/Profile::Jenkins::Master/Rosjenkins::Groovy[/tmp/configure_git_user.groovy]/Exec[/tmp/configure_git_user.groovy]/returns (notice): ERROR: Unexpected exception occurred while performing groovy command.
```

Any idea what this can mean? The only related settings in the deployment configuration are:

```
### GitHub pull-request builder settings
jenkins::github::username: ros-pull-request-builder
jenkins::github::token: somegithubtoken
```

which doesn't seem to relate or be required for the job. Do I have to have a github account to deploy the build farm?

**Comment by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) on 2019-08-21**:
@nuclearsandwich Thank you for the tip. I checked the log, but the job doesn't seem to check out anything. After outputting info about the used docker and issuing a warning about "no swap limit support", it only deletes and creates the docker_generae_release_jobs and reconfigure_jobs folders and then tries to run the command. No check-out or copying is performed.

I pasted the full log here: https://pastebin.com/8W6wHdF5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally was able to get it to work.

The first issue was caused by an outdated git plugin in Jenkins. After updating all the plugins, the job started checking out `ros_buildfarm` from github and used it.

The second issue seems to be that when generating the jobs with `ros_buildfarm`'s `generate_all_jobs.py` script, the job generation configuration of `ros_buildfarm_config` MUST be specified as an http link.

Before I had used:

```
generate_all_jobs.py --commit file:/path/to/my/local/ros_buildfarm_config/index.yaml
```

but it seems the provided link is saved in the jobs, which won't be able to access the file system.

So it must be:

```
generate_all_jobs.py --commit http://localhost_or_wherever/ros_buildfarm_config/index.yaml
```

---

Originally posted by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) with karma: 17 on 2019-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-22**:
Ah, yes. This was one of the first things I did wrong when just starting out.

This might actually be something to change in the various Python scripts in `ros_buildfarm` that accept these type of arguments. Just a check that no `file://` URIs are being passed in, or at least a very noticable warning.

Could be nice PR @max-krichenbauer.